# Extract cell value to only between the third '/' and the fourth '/'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Values in `column A`

```
/teams/brazil/esporte-clube-vitoria/306/
/teams/brazil/gremio-esportivo-brasil/6205/
```

Expected values:

```
esporte-clube-vitoria
gremio-esportivo-brasil
```

Formula that I currently use but that generates errors when used with ARRAYFORMULA for various values:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"/",REPT(" ",99)),299,99))))
```

**Is there a more reliable formula for this job?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(R1:R,"/\w+/\w+/|[0-9]|/",""))
```

[image]

> Formula that I currently use but that generates errors when used with ARRAYFORMULA for various values

*Cannot test if this formula works for other values unless you share them.*

One could also use

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(SPLIT(R2:R,"/"),,3))
```